# checking array length in switch statement

Tags: javascript

I am looking at using a `switch` statement to check if an array's length is greater than `0`. I could do this using an `if/else` statement but I want to get more comfortable using `switch` statements and am slightly baffled why the following doesn't work.

Given an array of numbers, my function determines whether the sum of all of the numbers is odd or even.

Here is what it looks like:

```
function oddOrEven(array) {

   switch(array) {
     case array.length === 0: 
       throw 'Error';
       break;

    case array.length > 0:
       answer = array.reduce((a, b)=>{
         return a + b;
       }) % 2 === 0 ? 'even' :  'odd'; 
       break;
   }
}
```

examples

```
oddOrEven([0]) returns "even"
oddOrEven([2, 5, 34, 6]) returns "odd"
oddOrEven([0, -1, -5]) returns "even"
```

I know I can do `if(array.length > 0)...` but as I said I want to get used to using switch statements and thought that this should also work.

Comment: Please re-read the documentation for `switch`. You may want to use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: @torazaburo so `if` and `switch` statements aren't used interchangeably?

Comment: Unless you want to use the `switch (true)` hack, which is frowned on, the `switch` statement is used for checking a particular expression against a set of possible values, so there are cases where it can replace an `if` statement, but other cases where it cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `switch`, you compare an expression to values, doing an action for each one. In your case, you could switch the `array.length` like that:

```
function oddOrEven(array) {

   switch(array.length) {
     case 0: 
       throw 'Error';
       break;

     default: // in that case, array.length != 0, not > 0 necessarily
       answer = array.reduce((a, b)=>{
         return a + b;
       }) % 2 === 0 ? 'even' :  'odd'; 
       break;
   }
}
```

However, in my opinion, `if/else` is the right one to be used here. It is worth to take a look at [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) for `switch` to understand the best scenarios in which it can be used.

Comment: ah, ok! this is what I wanted to clear things up. So when do you know whether you should use `switch` over `if/else`?

Comment: If/else is the more generic one, you can always use it, but if you want to compare a variable to a series of values, doing an action for each one, switch is cleaner! For example, if you want to do something if the length of the array is 0, another thing if it is 1, another one if it is 2; switch generates a cleaner code

Comment: cheers! i get it now! just needed something like this to clear up a few questions I had in my head

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic usage of the `switch` statement would be as follows:

```
 switch(array.length) {
     case 0: // ...
     default: // ...
 }
```

However, you are right in assuming that expressions can be used instead of values in the `case` labels. The following will work:

```js
function oddOrEven(array) {
  switch (true) {
    case array.length === 0:
      throw 'Error';

    case array.length > 0:
      return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
  }
}

console.log(oddOrEven([0]));
console.log(oddOrEven([2, 5, 34, 6]));
```

Obviously, using an `if` statement is the more readable approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good practice to do switch statements to check an array length. You should rather do it like this:

```
function oddOrEven(arr) {
   if(arr.length === 0) {
      throw 'Error';
   }
   return array.reduce((a, b)=>{
     return a + b;
   }) % 2 === 0 ? 'even' :  'odd'; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, but i know i could have used an `if/else`.  was just wondering about the `switch` equivalent